# How to apply a function inside a nested vector in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with nested fields such as:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(name_var = c("Abel","Abel", "Bill", "Bill", "Craig", "Craig", "Craig")
           , value_var = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
           , car_color = c("B","B","B","G","G","G","G") 
)

dt_2 <- dt[,.(.(.SD)), by = name_var]
```

The function below transforms data through an specified function:

```
transform_value <- function(x, fun, campo, ...) {
  x [, get (fun)(get(campo), ...)]
}
```

For instance, one may calculate the average from the `value_var` inside the nested `V1`:

```
dt_2[, mean_value:=lapply(V1, transform_value, "mean", "value_var")]
```

that corrrectly results in

```
   name_var           V1 mean_value
1:     Abel <data.table>        1.5
2:     Bill <data.table>        3.5
3:    Craig <data.table>          6
```

However, when I try to calculate the log of the nested `value_var` I get:

```
dt_2[, log_value:=lapply(V1, transform_value, "log", "value_var")]
```

that results in:

```
   name_var           V1 mean_value                  log_value
1:     Abel <data.table>        1.5        0.0000000,0.6931472
2:     Bill <data.table>        3.5          1.098612,1.386294
3:    Craig <data.table>          6 1.609438,1.791759,1.945910
```

Although the values are correct, actually I would like to have the log values side by side inside the `V1`, such as:

```
> dt_2$V1[[1]]

   value_var car_color  log_value
1:         1         B  0.0000000
2:         2         B  0.6931472
```

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` works because it returns a scalar value when given a vector whereas `log` returns a vector. Here is an option to modify your function:

```
transform_value <- function(x, fun, campo, ...) {
    a <- x[, c(.SD, .(match.fun(fun)(get(campo), ...)))]
    setnames(a, names(a)[length(a)], paste0(fun, "_value"))
}

dt_2[, V1 := lapply(V1, transform_value, "log", "value_var")]
```

`dt_2$V1`:

```
[[1]]
   value_var car_color log_value
1:         1         B 0.0000000
2:         2         B 0.6931472

[[2]]
   value_var car_color log_value
1:         3         B  1.098612
2:         4         G  1.386294

[[3]]
   value_var car_color log_value
1:         5         G  1.609438
2:         6         G  1.791759
3:         7         G  1.945910
```

Comment: Thank you chinsoon12, great insight, I have already accepted your answer (made just an adjustment, changing "mean" to "log" in the last line of your proposed code) . Regards